# Vis Network + Vuetify Tabs - Networks won't fill screen

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vis.js

I am having some problems getting some Vis JS Networks to fill the available space under the App Bar correctly in a '' element. The graph element will fill the space, but the 100% I height I have had to apply to both '.v-tabs-items' and '.v-window-item' seems to ignore the padding and creates a scroll-bar, I have also set 100% width and there is no horizontal scroll.

It also doesn't adjust properly when resizing the window, requiring a tab switch to readjust to the correct size.

If I remove the 100% Height and Width then the tab content is constrained to a small rectange.

I have simplified the relevant code and it is below, there are two parts, the App.Vue file which contains the main screen and also the GraphView.Vue file which contains the Component that is used to draw the graph.

### App.Vue

```js
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>Test</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <template v-slot:extension>
        <v-tabs v-model="graphTab">
          <v-tab v-for="(graph, title) in getGraphData()" :key="title">
            {{ title }}
            <span style="display: none"> {{ graph }}</span>
          </v-tab>
        </v-tabs>
      </template>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-tabs-items v-model="graphTab">
          <v-tab-item v-for="(graph, title) in getGraphData()" :key="title">
            <GraphView
              :nodes="graph.nodes"
              :edges="graph.edges"
              :options="defaultVisOptions"
            ></GraphView>
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs-items>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import GraphView from "./components/GraphView";
import { DataSet } from "vis-network";
const defaultVisOptions = {
  autoResize: true,
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  edges: {
    arrows: "to"
  },
  nodes: {
    shape: "circle"
  }
};
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    GraphView
  },
  data: () => ({
    defaultVisOptions: defaultVisOptions,
    graphTab: null
  }),
  methods: {
    getGraphData: function() {
      return {
        "Graph 1": {
          nodes: new DataSet([
            { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
            { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
            { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
            { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
            { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
          ]),
          edges: new DataSet([
            { from: 1, to: 3 },
            { from: 1, to: 2 },
            { from: 2, to: 4 },
            { from: 2, to: 5 }
          ])
        },
        "Graph 2": {
          nodes: new DataSet([
            { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
            { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
            { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
            { id: 4, label: "Node 4" },
            { id: 5, label: "Node 5" }
          ]),
          edges: new DataSet([
            { from: 1, to: 2 },
            { from: 2, to: 3 },
            { from: 3, to: 4 },
            { from: 4, to: 5 }
          ])
        }
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.v-tabs-items {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.v-window-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

### GraphView.Vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="graphContainer" ref="graphContainer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { Network } from "vis-network";
export default {
  name: "GraphView",
  props: ["nodes", "edges", "options"],
  mounted() {
    this.network = new Network(
      this.$refs.graphContainer,
      { nodes: this.$props.nodes, edges: this.$props.edges },
      this.$props.options
    );
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.graphContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

As explained above, the expected result is that the Graphs fill the available space without creating scroll bars but this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it with your code but the container should be styled like:

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div
    style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;"
    ref="graphContainer"
  />
</div>
```

This way it will fill all available space (you may need to set `position: relative` on the parent) without stretching it any further.